# PROLOG Uncle relationship without brother

Tags: prolog, logic

I'm just starting to learn PROLOG and I was given the task of creating both a **aunt/uncle** relationship in a family tree. The aunt can be created using a *sister* relationship, however, the uncle relationship must be created without it.

The current predicates are: *male, female, parent*
& the rules created so far are: *father, mother, grandfather, grandmother, sister*

Here's what I have so far:

```
sister(Sister,Individual):- 
female(Sister),
parent(X,Sister),
parent(X,Individual), 
Sister \= Individual.

aunt(Aunt, Individual):- sister(Aunt, X), parent(X, Individual).
```

How would I go about creating the **uncle** relationship without the use of brother? I understand that the parent(parent(Individual)) == parent(uncle) but how would I go about stating that given my current relations?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't consider myself the best with Prolog, but I believe this will work.  Please comment on anything that may be incorrect and I'll fix it!

We know the following:

- The uncle of the individual must be male.
- The uncle would share a parent with the individual's parent.

Therefore, we can define the rule as follows:

```
uncle(Uncle, Individual) :- 
    male(Uncle),            % The uncle must be male.
    parent(X, Individual),  % Assume there's some parent of the individual, X.
    parent(Y, Uncle),       % Assume there's some parent of the uncle, Y.
    parent(Y, X).           % Y must be the parent of X.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I have a follow up question and I'm not sure if it applies at all: Do you have to account for if you get the MALE parent for the Individual and the FEMALE parent for the Uncle? Or vice versa?

EDIT: NVM, dumb question! We're checking if the uncles parent (whether male or female) is also a parent of X, correct?

Comment: I don't believe you have to account for that, as the shared parent can either be the mother or the father.

Comment: Yes, because `X` is a parent to `Individual`